# Forward mail and add content to body (Outlook 2007, VBA)

Tags: vba, email, outlook, ms-office, forward

Can anyone help me with editing the VBA-Code for the following Problem:
I want to forward e-mails with a specific subject to an specific E-Mail. In this process i want to add a text to the forwarded body. 
Thank's for your help!

edit.

I have the code now, but it doesn't work properly. It sends the last E-Mail clicked on :(.

```
Sub Test(oMail As MailItem)
Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim obj_curitem As MailItem
Dim obj_newitem
Dim obj_Selection
Dim obj_curfolder
Dim obj_msgitems
Dim Forward As Object

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Set obj_Selection = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If obj_Selection.Count > 0 Then

        For Each obj_curitem In obj_Selection
            strID = obj_curitem.EntryID
            Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

            'Object auf einem neuen Item erstellen
            Set obj_newitem = obj_curitem.Forward
            With obj_curitem.Forward
                .Forward = True
                .SentOnBehalfOfName = "###"  'Deine Mailadresse
                .Subject = "WG" & .Subject                      'Betreff
                .To = "###"                    'Empfängermail
                .BODY = "geprüft" & .BODY                       'E-Mail Inhalt
                .Send

            End With
        Next
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What code do you have now?

Answer (score 0):

In general you will need to handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686.aspx) event of the Application class where you can check out the Subject property and decide whether to forward the email or not. The [Forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865399.aspx) method of the Application class allows you doing so - it executes the Forward action for an item and returns the resulting copy as a MailItem object.

This `NewMailEx` event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The EntryIDsCollection string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.  You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the `NameSpace.GetItemFromID` method and process the item.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body. So, **you can use the Word object model do whatever you need with the message body**.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help in advance.